# ZTE ZXHN H208N Modem Issues (Wireless/Ethernet)

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, ethernet, modem

Wireless & Ethernet on this modem won't work corectly (tried both methods)

It connect fine but  neither  programs  connect very slowly or won’t connect at all

Major apps (like updater) sometimes wont connect to Insternet (no Internet error)

and conecting to repositories takes over a minute BUT download speed's are still high.

Also I have to point out Wireless works fine on other networks

I’ve done a little bit of research and I found that I need to change modems channels but either this wont work

I'll apreciate your help

Comment: I'm not sure which methods you tried to make it work, but from what I see it's not an Ubuntu issue, it's a connection issue.

Comment: It conects completely fine on Windows,I find it very strange that it dosen't work right on Ubuntu or any Linux Distro

Comment: Try the instruction in this video, I don't have a modem like it so I can't test it for you `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_DJEIFw7bA`